# Get Sound volume size of android : Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have developed game in unity3d.

In that game, i have given option for setting sound volume sound which affects my game sound object only, This does not relate with the android sound setting.

But i just want to check whether my android device is set to mute or not. If my device setting is mute then i will keep my game sound volume size value to 0.

But i am not getting the way to find the android device sound status,..if anyone is having idea then please guide me.

Thanks in advance for your support and help..

Answer (score 3):

You can get the level of sound from your device this way:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int levelSound = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

You need to know the stream you are using, normally Music for any multimedia sound (music, games, films, etc...)

You can check also this, to know the mode of the phone right now:

```
manager.getRingerMode();
```

Comment: ahhm ok, i misunderstood your question